# NUnit grouping asserts in parallel testing

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

I want to run NUNit tests in parallel because I have heavy wait conditions that end up in massively long test runs in a sequential manner. This simplified structure outlined below suits all my needs however, it seems that NUnit is grouping the asserts when I call the `TestParallel` method

```
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.Fail("Test1 Failure");
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Assert.Fail("Test2 Failure");
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestParallel()
    {
        var toRun = new Task[]
        {
            Task.Run(() => Test1()),
            Task.Run(() => Test2())
        };
        Task.WaitAll(toRun);
    }
}
```

Both tests fail as expected however, the second failing test also displays the first failing tests assert exception like so:

```
NUnit.Framework.AssertionException: 'Multiple failures or warnings in test:
  1) Test1 Failure
  2) Test2 Failure
'
```

[image]

What options do I have to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It's NUnit's job to run your tests, not yours. :-)

In your code, you have given NUnit three tests to run, Test1, Test2 and TestParallel. It does so but TestParallel is also launching Test1 and Test2 a second time. Their assertions are considered part of TestParallel and are reported accordingly.

You could, of course, remove the `[Test]` attribute from Test1 and Test2, leaving yourself only one test which incorporates the other two. That's not an approach that scales very well.

The more natural approach would be to have NUnit run the tests in parallel rather than doing it yourself. To accomplish that, add `[Parallelizable]` to Test1 and Test2 and remove TestParallel.

Comment: `[Parallelizable]` was the first resource I looked into but unfortunately that is not an option because of the size and tech debt of the existing library. In actual use the `TestParallel` method performs reflection on the assembly, creates new instances of the TestClasses, and executes matching methods according to the TestIds discovered at run time.

Comment: In that case, you actually have taken over the job of running tests and the first option would be your best bet. Given that you are doing so much, I'm wondering why you are doing it as a hybrid of your own code and NUnit, rather than as a runner of your own.

Comment: Because there are multiple CI processes that require different tests to be ran under different conditions, and instead of consulting with the devops engineer which tests to run by passing in the tests via command-line as a build step, the CI pipeline is set to only run TestParallel. Which pulls from an API dynamically at runtime and only executes which tests it finds within the assembly that match the criteria.

Comment: Understood. To do it without involving NUnit as I suggested would be a big effort - approximately the size of NUnit itself. :-)